# Cannot Override Magento Block (Possibly Cache Related)

Tags: php, magento

For some odd reason I cannot override `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` on my production server.

I have Magento running locally where I develop, then I rsync to my production server, so I'm pretty sure that the filesystems are the same (other than caches).

Here's what I've done so far - please note that this is working *perfectly* locally, just not on my production server for some reason:

- Created `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php` to override the Core version.
- Added necessary code, tested locally, works fine. The updated code simply updates the `_getProductCollection()` function so that Magento sorts products in descending order by created_at date if `$_GET['newest']` is set. This works fine locally
- rsync'ed my updates to the production server. Didn't work, so I assumed it was cache-related.
- Turned off caches, refreshed indexes. Still nothing.
- Deleted `var/cache` files, still nothing.
- Compared backend configuration to see if anything was off. Everything looks good.
- Added invalid code in my new block (List.php) on the production version so that it would   cause an error. No error (?!). It's as if the new file I uploaded is being ignored.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, as I am at a loss for ideas.

I'm on Magento v 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your production server using [Magento compilation](http://alanstorm.com/magento_compiler_path) mode? Magento compilation mode isn't really a compilation, it just copies all your class files out of the code cools, and places then in a single folder.  This speeds up PHP (particularly older versions) tremendously.  If you've uploaded a new file to the local code pool for an override and you're using compilation mode, you'll probably need to recompile your classes (`System -> Tools -> Compiler`, or the command line scripts in the `shell/` folder).

Also, is your production system using APC?  If so, then PHP has cached the old version of the class into APC, and won't look at your new version until you clear the APC cache.

Finally — are you uploading from a Mac/Windows machine to a unix environment?  If so, try looking REALLY HARD at the file for case sensitivity errors.  I usually go as far to try explicit `ls`'s from the root folder to make sure the file paths are named like I think they are.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I wish I could give you a million upvotes! Recompilation solved the issue. I literally spent hours trying to solve this. Thanks!